# Mobile web page - where to keep private data on devices?

Tags: android, html, iphone, cookies, mobile

I'm developing a mobile website and I have one problem with the security of some of the data.

The first time a user browses my site, the page requests a server to get some private user's data (i.e. RSA private key) which is used in future operations. This private key must be stored somewhere in local device memory (as a file on device, browser cache...).

The next time when the same user launches the page (some functionality on page), the page has to load the file from local data when needed and use it (i.e., encrypt some string with private key).

The problem is: Where should this key be store and how can it be read?

First, I thought about cookies. But the cookie will be sent with all requests, so doing it with private key IMHO is not a good idea.
The connection of course will be via SSL, but even that I don't want to send the private key to the server (it has to be as secure as possible!).

So, how can I solve to problem...?

I can add, it's not necessary to get the private key from the server. It can be loaded as a file to the device via its file manager or something like that. Simply - the browser has to read the private key when it will be needed and use it. I don't think that browser allows to save/read file from JavaScript, am I right?

The solution of the problem must work on most of available devices and browsers nowadays (especially iPhone, Android, Symbian + Opera Mobile (/Mini?).

Maybe HTML5 and its 'localStorage' could solve it, but I have to assume, I *can’t* use HMTL5 with all its features.
I consider using the [jQuery Mobile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile) framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the WebSetting object on the instance of WebView and in that class this is the method using which you can set the path @ where you can set the path to the private area

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCachePath(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I suppose it works only on Android, I'm right? It must be solution that works on iPhone, Symbian, Opera Mobile, etc. also.

Comment: There will be no any generic code which works uniformly on all platforms you specified because each platform is different conventions, restrictions and API set. If you intended to get a solution for all platforms, you should tag like that

Comment: I set "iphone" tag before, to show I need solution that works not only on one plaform.
I wrote I wanted to use cookies because generally all browsers work similiar to each other. 
But it solution has disadvantages and I can't do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

[CanIUse.com](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=storage) has a good overview of what browsers support localStorage.

You could also encrypt the private key using JavaScript. This won't add much security, but may help a bit if someone finds the browser cache files.